# which are considered vs considered

Tags: grammar

"Red apples, considered in this work, are tasty"
vs
"Red apples, which are considered in this work, are tasty."

I learned English intuitively by watching movies, reading books and stuff. Therefore I have no explicit rules (that I've learned/know about) when creating my own sentences except my own experience and examples from sentences I've read before. From my experience I would always go with the first option. But I've also heard the second one. Could somebody tell me whether only one or both are correct?

(Also my comma placement is more or less completely random.)

Comment: Is your intent to say two things: 1.  Red apples are tasty. 2. We considered red apples in this work.  Or one thing: “We only considered tasty red apples in this work.”

Comment: @Jim My intent is to say two things. (The first of your proposed options.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.

Main/Principal Clause- Red apples are tasty.

Dependent/Subordinate Clause- which are considered in this work

'Which' introduces a relative clause. 'Which' is a relative pronoun. It refers to 'red apples'.

We can leave out 'which are' (which + 'be' verb).